# log-likelihood value (switching from positive to negative)

Tags: maximum-likelihood, scale-invariance

I have a question about M.L estimation.

When I estimated the AR(1)- GARCH(1,1) using log returns, the value of the log-likelihood is positive (see bellow):

```
                              Standard          t     
 Parameter       Value          Error       Statistic 
-----------   -----------   ------------   -----------
 Constant    9.16175e-05   3.24078e-06        28.2702
 GARCH{1}       0.776593    0.00637061        121.903
  ARCH{1}       0.223407     0.0103663        21.5513
```

logL = 3.8402e+03

Using the same log returns multiplied by 100 I got the follwing result:

```
                              Standard          t     
 Parameter       Value          Error       Statistic 
-----------   -----------   ------------   -----------
 Constant        0.91638     0.0325203        28.1787
 GARCH{1}       0.776569    0.00637141        121.883
  ARCH{1}       0.223431     0.0103645        21.5574
```

logL = -6.5997e+03

The change of the volatility level makes sense for me, but why the value of the log-likelihood became negative ??

Best Regards

Comment: If you scale the numbers you change their variance, so you change the value of the density (under the model), so you change the likelihood. With a continuous density, there's nothing that requires log-likelihood to have one sign or another. Most commonly people asking here are concerned why it can come out positive rather than negative.

Comment: I should probably post that as an answer; I was hoping someone would come with a more expansive one.

Answer (score 1):

If you multiply values by a constant, you change their standard deviation (it gets multiplied by that constant), so if the model has a scale parameter you change the height of the density under the model everywhere (it must be divided by the same constant, to keep the area 1).

[image: Drawing of two symmetric densities showing height changing with spread]

If you change the height of the fitted density, you will change the height of the likelihood function everywhere, including at the maximum.

With a continuous density, there's nothing that requires log-likelihood to have one sign or another, so by an appropriate choice of that scaling constant you could move it from positive to negative or negative to positive.